# Maintaining state/content loaded in via AJAX on manual page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, sinatra

This jQuery/History.js code works for loading in content via Ajax by clicking a link and navigating back/forward in the browser, but on manual page refresh the history stack/log is lost and instead of just loading in the same content I loaded in prior I get the actual .erb file and lose the styling/formatting of the page.

```
$(function(){
  $('.nav-bar li a').on('click', function(event){
    var urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
    // not implemeneted
    var title = urlPath.capitalize();

    loadContent(urlPath);

    // pushes the current page state onto the history stack, and changes the URL
    History.pushState('', null, urlPath);
    event.preventDefault();
  });



  // This event makes sure that the back/forward buttons work too
  window.onpopstate = function(event){
    console.log("pathname: " + location.pathname);
    loadContent(location.pathname);
  };
});

function loadContent(url){
  // Uses jQuery to load the content
  $('#content').load(url+'#content', function(){
    console.log("Ajax success"); // Ajax

    // bxSlider image slider
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true
    });
  });
}

String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
  // add capitalize to string - uppercase the first character, add it to the rest of the  word 
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

How do I persist data / the history across a manual page refresh? I tried setting the current html to a variable and passing it as a JSON object for the first argument in pushState() but I  believe I might have been doing it wrong. What's the best way to implement this? Also, the window.onpopstate function is not run on a manual page refresh so I'm not sure how I would access the object and get the data anyway.

I'm not sure how relevant this is... but I'm running this application in Sinatra

My layout.erb

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>/title>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"  rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" media="screen"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="//browserstate.github.io/history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js">  </script>

   <script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
   <link href="/css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   <script src="/js/application.js"></script>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
   </head>

  <body>
   <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/" id="nav-bar">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about" id="nav-bar">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio" id="nav-bar">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="resume" id="nav-bar">Resume</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
```

The rest of my .erb views consist of a div with an ID of content and other HTML markup inside of them. Also, when the ajax call works, it seems to append a second div with an ID of content upon ajax success. How do I prevent that?

TL;DR

How to maintain page state with manual refresh, instead of loading in the actual view and losing the formatting/styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined

```
   // This event makes sure that the back/forward buttons work too
   window.onpopstate = function(event){
     console.log("pathname: " + location.pathname);
     loadContent(location.pathname);
   };
```

within a jQuery block:

```
 $(function(){
   ...
 )
```

This forces it to be ran after the document has loaded, so it isn't defined until after the first popstate event has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`, that in the first page store you data and at any other page you get your again.